# Deleted BOOTCAMP partition capacity went into Recovery HD

Tags: macos, partitioning, boot-camp

I am facing a weird problem and it is honestly driving me crazy!

I had a bootcamp partition (80 Go) with Windows 7 installed for a while. I then tried to remove this partition using Apple's Bootcamp Assistant but I encountered an error and was not able to do so. So I decided to boot in Recovery Mode, formatted the `BOOTCAMP` partition in the hope that I would later be able to merge it with my `Macintosh HD` one.

I succeeded in doing this, meaning that I then had `Macintosh HD` on one side, and an empty 80 Go `BOOTCAMP` partition on the other.

However, something went wrong in the process of merging them together and for some reason, I now have a capacity of 420 Go displayed on `Macintosh HD` (same as before), no `BOOTCAMP` partition displayed at all, and a `diskutil list` command showing me 80 Go for `Apple Recovery HD` (which correspond to my initial BOOTCAMP capacity):

```
➜  ~  diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            419.4 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             80.5 GB    disk0s3
```

When I launch the `First Aid` option in `Disk Utility` on `Apple SSD`, I get the following:

[image]

My only wish is to be able to recover my full 500 Go on `Macintosh HD` in order to later use bootcamp again and install Windows 10.

Looking forward to any kind of help,

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I recently had some trouble with the partition scheme on a Linux machine and at the end of the day the easiest thing to do was to wipe everything and restore from backup. If you've got a Time Machine backup of your Mac this is what I'd recommend.

Answer (score 0):

Disk First Aid might be reporting that the GPT partition table and the MBR partition table disagree with each other about your partition map.  You can confirm this by typing `fdisk /dev/disk0` from a terminal window.  See if `fdisk` reports a different partition layout than `diskutil` does.

Are you trying to recover the former Boot Camp partition or are you just trying to clear the error so you can use it to partition your disk again?

If your goal is to merely clear the error, use `fdisk` to remove all partitions and create a single partition, type `EE`, starting on sector 1 and ending on the last sector of the drive.  This is what a 'normal' GPT partition's MBR protective partition looks like.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I've found a simple solution for my problem. For anyone experiencing the same issues, here's how I did it:

1. Format Recovery HD
2. Expand Macintosh HD through Disk Utility (now possible since Recovery HD is empty). Simply clicking on the empty part of the pie that represents the recovery partition and hitting "minus".
3. Recreate Recovery HD using [Recovery Partition Creator 3.8](http://musings.silvertooth.us/2014/07/recovery-partition-creator-3-8/)

It worked flawlessly. I now have a fully-working Macintosh HD partition (500go), and a recovery partition that is only 650 Mb. I am able to boot on both Macintosh HD and Recovery HD, and the recovery tools report no errors.